# Add external email for google apps user

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've tried this code in a Google Spreadsheet Script to add another (external) email for my Google Apps Domain users:

```js
function createExternalEmail() {
  var userId = "sampleuser@mydomain.org";
  var update = {
    emails:
    {
      address: "sampleuser@homeemail.com",
      type: "home",
      customType: "",
      primary: false
    }, 
    addresses:
    {
      type: "home",
      customType: "",
      streetAddress: "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway",
      locality: "Mountain View",
      region: "CA",
      postalCode: "94043"
 }
  }
    update = AdminDirectory.Users.update(update, userId);
    var user = AdminDirectory.Users.get(userId);
    Logger.log('User emails:\n %s', JSON.stringify(user.emails, null, 2));
    Logger.log('User addresses:\n %s', JSON.stringify(user.addresses, null, 2));
}
```

But the updated values are not returned in the Logger.log. What's missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Admin SDK Reference](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users), `emails` and `addresses` are lists (arrays). You've provided objects in your update. Enclose them in square braces to make them one-element arrays.

Try:

```
function createExternalEmail() {
  var userId = "sampleuser@mydomain.org";
  var update = {
      emails:
      [{
        address: "sampleuser@homeemail.com",
        type: "home",
        customType: "",
        primary: false
      }], 
      addresses:
      [{
        type: "home",
        customType: "",
        streetAddress: "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway",
        locality: "Mountain View",
        region: "CA",
        postalCode: "94043"
      }]
    }
    update = AdminDirectory.Users.update(update, userId);  // You should check your response!!!
    var user = AdminDirectory.Users.get(userId);
    Logger.log('User emails:\n %s', JSON.stringify(user.emails, null, 2));
    Logger.log('User addresses:\n %s', JSON.stringify(user.addresses, null, 2));
}
```

Comment: Excellent. I had it with the square braces at one point but I kept giving me errors. How do I check responses.

Comment: API doc says "If successful, this method returns an [Users resource](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users#resource) in the response body." If unsuccessful, then, I'd anticipate some other response. (NULL? 0? Error String? Exception? Not documented, so you'd need to experiment to know.) Through the [Try It](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/update#try-it) link, an exception is generated - but that doesn't mean the same behavior flows through the GAS API. You can check the response is non-null or the type of response is a user.